# SQL Server: do readers wait on writers (for same data)?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, locking

I've read that in older versions of SQL Server .. it had a pessimistic locking strategy. I.e. readers wait on writers for access to the same data (row or page level), unlike Oracle.

Is this still the case in newer versions ? I've read that the locking strategy has been changed in recent versions.

Comment: It depends on the [transaction isolation level](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you heard of is the [`SNAPSHOT ISOLATION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcbchxcb%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), available since SQL Server 2005. Snapshot isolation, aka. row-versioning, is the default behavior in Oracle. You can make it default in SQL Server too, by enabling `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` on the database:

```
ALTER DATABASE [<dbname>] SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON;
```

With row versioning SQL Server does not acquire data locks during reads. If concurrent writes occur, the read will fetch the previous version of the row. For more details, read [Row Versioning-based Isolation Levels in the Database Engine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177404.aspx).

You should not confuse row versioning and snapshot with dirty reads. Dirty reads offer [inconsistent data](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlcat/archive/2007/02/01/previously-committed-rows-might-be-missed-if-nolock-hint-is-used.aspx) which makes programming a challenge, to say the least (ie. you should not use it!). Snapshot reads offer always a transactionally consistent image of the data.

Answer (score 2):

by default SQL server uses **READ COMMITTED** isolation level, which means it will wait on uncommited changes before it tries to read them.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx

note that if you don't care about the accuracy of the data returned, you can always set you isolation level to **Read Uncommitted** this will give you all the records evening the ones that have binding changes

You can also use **snapshot** isolation level, which will give you all the record, including the latest known version of data that are currently being modified, **without** the current modification.

Comment: No mention of snapshot isolation?

Comment: Please note that READ UNCOMMITTED (and the WITH NOLOCK hint) will in some cases cause you to not get already committed data. See http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlcat/archive/2007/02/01/previously-committed-rows-might-be-missed-if-nolock-hint-is-used.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The locking strategy is something that is handled on connection by connection basis - this is something that can be set by the application and withing SQL Server itself.

Read about the [Transaction Isolation Levels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx) for more details.